# About the multiplicity of intersection in projective space

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

I found this statement, and I can't get a proof:

Given $X\subset \mathbb{P}^{n}$ an irreducible projective set of dimension $d$ and degree $e$, and given $H_{1},...,H_{d}$ hypersurfaces with degrees $e_{1},...,e_{d}$, respectively, such that $X\cap H_{1}\cap...\cap H_{d}$ is a finite set of points, then the number of points is precisely $ee_{1}...e_{d}$, counted with multiplicity.

Nothing is assumed about the regularity of the sequence of the polynomials defining the hypersurfaces.

Could anyone give me a hint about how can it be proven?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: See for example Fulton's *Intersection Theory*, Prop. 8.4.

Comment: If you want to prove it yourself, I think you should be able to do it using Hilbert polynomials (use additivity in short exact sequences).

Comment: See Harris *Algebraic Geometry (a first course)*, Theorem 18.4 (perhaps less intimidating than Fulton).

Comment: Thanks! My first approach was using Hilbert polynomial, but I’m not sure how to get rid of the undesirable embedded components that may appear when treating with the sum of the ideals, just to get nice exact sequences that give you the degree of the intersection (counting multiplicity)